# POST to password protected URL?

Tags: php, jquery, user-interface, post

I am working on a project that requires me to POST some data to a url that requires a username and password for access. How do I build the URL so that it automatically logs into the system?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://xxxxxxx",
    type: "POST",
    data: "___PUT_BODY___="+file+"&file="+time,
})
```

Comment: Does it use HTTP Basic authentication or something custom & HTML-based?

Answer (score 6):

If the page uses "Basic" HTTP authentication (the kind where the browser opens a little dialog window asking for a username and password), you can simply do:

```
https://username:password@www.example.com/
```

If the site has a login form embedded on the page somewhere, then the login information doesn't go in the URL. You would have to simulate submitting that form (by generating a similar AJAX request specifically for logging in).

Comment: I agree with votey, but my 2 cents is that I tend to use custom lockouts for my secure pages, and use unique tokens to grant necessary access. So my post would have data as {file: file, token:token} where the url is a lockout bypass that checks the token and referring site to validate access. Sounds complex but it is not. You can do this with basic sessions and a login form. Maybe 20 minutes to set up.

Comment: "If the server performs HTTP authentication before providing a response, the user name and password pair can be sent via the username and password options."

Answer (score 2):

[Read the funny manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Also, don't make your query string the way it comes out in the URI bar, make it an object.
Also, semi-colon goes at the end of that statement.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
            "___PUT_BODY___="   : file, 
            "&file="            : time
          },
    password : "theP4s$w0rD!",
    username : "Bob's big bad world of HTTP Auth"

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the page you send from is public, of if the username/password have to remain private you should reconsider putting your username/password in the page.

You can post to a local page on your server, wich in turn can send the data with for example curl to the receiving server.

Also useing curl you can do any kind of authentication you need to.